# Is there a cartoon guide to OOP?

Tags: oop, drawing

I'm looking for some visuals for a presentation to illustrate the principles of oop in a simple-to-grasp way.

I want to avoid saying stuff like "**an object is a software bundle of related state and behavior**".

Has anyone seen a non-jargon-y illustrated guide to OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illustrations in Grady Booch's book [Object Oriented Analysis & Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805353402) are pretty good , and quite funny!

Answer (score 3):

O'Reilly's book [Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678) may fullfil your needs

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just thought of cars as an example of OO design. There's a fixed interface: accelerator, brake, clutch, steering wheel, gears, lights, indicators and so on. There's also different implementations of the underlying 'object': petrol, hybrid, electric. Inheritance - manual transmission inherits from automatic transmission but adds a gear lever and clutch.

Comment: I would say that an automatic transmission inherits from a manual, probably because an auto is more complex, so it would require more logic. I'm pretty pedantic though.

Comment: @AF - There will be some pedants in the audience so I take your point.

Comment: @AF - I guess it's all down to your point of view. From a user it would be manual inherits auto since interface more complex. For implementor it would be auto inherits manual because implementation more complex. Which denomstrates that there is no 'right' way.

Comment: It sounds like both inherit from "transmission" since one adds more ui elements, and one adds more processing machinery.

Comment: Automatic->Transmission->VehiclePart->Object->JonSkeet

Comment: would it be right to say Automatic is a facade pattern over Manual ?